# work with a florist (What's the meaning of 'a florist'?)

Tags: phrase-meaning

> work with a florist (What's the literal meaning of 'a florist'?)

1. a person who works at a flower shop
2. a flower shop

my dictionary explains the meaning as 2

source: https://en.dict.naver.com/#/entry/enko/3580c75c47e446d1a14302fc22c5b138

(P.S. edit)
I have known 'a florist' as a person who works at a flower shop but one dictionary says as above it's also 'a flower shop'. If someone says "I work with a florist", What could be the first response of the native English speakers:

1. The florist(person) is a man or woman?
2. The florist(shop) pays well?

I'd like to know if the second usage(as a shop) is okay to use in conversation and wonder if it could be a broken English.

Comment: What dictionary is that? I've just checked several dictionaries, and they all agree with me and [Collins](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/florist) that the noun **florist** means *a person who works in a flower shop (a shop that sells cut flowers and plants for inside the house)*. The shop itself is called a **florist's** (note the possessive), same as *the baker's, the grocer's,...*

Comment: https://en.dict.naver.com/#/entry/enen/61893fc839d649f584cc186e84e37bd6

Comment: In your link: 1. NOUN A florist is a shopkeeper who arranges and sells flowers and sells house plants. 2. NOUN A florist or a florist's is a shop where flowers and house plants are sold. What is not clear?

Comment: The *first* definition in your link clearly agrees with the rest of us! The second definition is *A **florist** or a **florist's** is **a shop** where flowers and house plants are sold.* The main reason people might use the bare noun (without possessive) for the shop as well as the worker is simply that it's a little bit difficult to actually *enunciate* the extra /s/ after ***-ist***. That not the case with similar words like *baker, butcher, grocer,...,* where that possessive /s/ is ***always*** enunciated when referring to the shop itself rather than the worker / owner.

Comment: I first thought when I came across the example sentence that 'work with a florist' means: work (together) with a person who arranges and sells flowers.

Comment: @Brandon - that is 'work with a florist' means. Meaning no. 1 in your dictionary.

Comment: I was not sure that 'a florist' could also mean 'a shop' because I thought it needed ''s' to be a shop.

Comment: @FumbleFingers has explained that above.

Comment: I personally think 'a florist' should be a person. To mean a shop, it requires ''s'. It's not a standard English without the ''s' and that's why I asked the LITERAL meaning of 'a florist'.

Comment: I have just visited the websites of floral shops in several cities in the US, and many of them call themselves a **florist**. What you or anyone else personally thinks is irrelevant.

Comment: The precise status of *[apostrophe +] **possessive /s/*** in relation to retail or other commercial premises is a bit vague. The apostrophe is usually present in ***Sainsbury's***, but almost never in ***Boots***, despite the fact that *syntactically* it's the same construction. Plus we rarely attach even the /s/ with ***Asda***, and *never* with *[the] **Co-op***. It's a minefield of different rules indifferently applied with different business names.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney: Can you give any specific *examples* where a company refers to ***its own actual flower shop*** as a "florist"? I wonder if you're just misinterpreting the usage in contexts where the company is referring to ***itself*** as "a florist".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Until your comment, no one here had made a distinction between a shop and a company, only between a shop and a person. I suppose it's interesting in a way . . . but I've been as helpful here as I care to be.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney -British English seems to use _florist_' and _florist's_ interchangeably. "Tina Adams, 62, who owns a florist in the High Street, said the flat above her old shop, just a few doors down the road from her new one, was also haunted." and "The man, thought to be in his 40s, was painting the front of a florist's in the High Street last night. But he got into difficulties when ..." from newspapers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Florist can mean either

1. a person who arranges or sells flowers
2. a shop where a florist works (also called a "florist's")

In sense one:

> The party planner will *work with a florist* to decorate the hall for the wedding.

In sense two

> Tina Adams, 62, who *owns a florist* in the High Street, said the flat above her old shop, just a few doors down the road from her new one, was also haunted.

The sentence "I work with a florist" strongly suggests the sense one. Sense two is clearly an extension of sense one. (The translation in your dictionary is a rather free translation, changing "I work with a florist" to "I work in a flower shop")